# Outputting log during rsubmit

Tags: sas

I currently have a SAS process where I create ~ 30 datasets in an rsubmit and the runtime is > 1 hour.

I find it frustrating that I only get to see the log after all the processing is done, so I can't check progress as I go.  Is there anyway to get the log to update after each data set is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, divide your program up into blocks delimited by `rsubmit;` and `endrsubmit;` statements:

```
rsubmit;
data want1;
  set have1;
run;
endrsubmit;

rsubmit;
data want2;
  set have2;
run;
endrsubmit;
```

Your SAS/CONNECT connection is not terminated on submission of an `endrsubmit;` statement, but the log will return the messages generated at that point, before continuing with the next `rsubmit` block.

Alternatively, if you have access to the remote server, you could find the destination files and see which have been created/most recently modified etc.